# ¿Cómo se implementa la herencia múltiple para las interfaces en Java 8 y evistar la ambigüedad?

Tags: java, java-ee

¿Cómo se implementa la herencia múltiple para las interfaces en Java 8? , tengo algunas dudas con el ejemplo que he estado desarrollando, resulta que tengo dos Interfaces que implementan método default con la misma firma, pero al momento de implementarla en una clase normal  pues me genera ambigüedad y esta no compila:

```
interface walk{
  default int  run(){
  return 10;
 }
}
   interface Run{
   default int  run(){
    return 100;
   }
}
```

Mi clase que implementa estas interfaces

```
public class Clasee implements Run, walk   <---genera error Como se soluciona? 
{
public static final void main (String ... x){
System.out.println(new Clasee().run() );
 }
}
```

Por otro lado si solamente tuviera en mis interfaces métodos abstractos con la misma firma al implementarlo en mi clase cual se implementa primero el de la clase Walk o Run

```
interface walk{
    int  run();

}

interface Run{
    int  run();

}

public class Clasee implements Run, walk   <-cual se implementa primero? 
{
    public static final void main (String ... x){
    System.out.println(new Clasee().run() );
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Por que dentro de la interfaz `walk` defines un metodo `run`, eso como que no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: son los nuevas implementaciones de java 8 de los metodos default  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html y solamente practico

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de las interfaces con default methods esto es el famoso **[Diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance)**. Java por lo menos te avisa y no te lo permite, otros lenguajes te dejan hacer este tipo de cosas y luego todo son problemas.

En el caso de las interfaces **normales** - tienes el mismo método, con la misma firma y todo lo demás. Lo implementas una vez y listo. No se puede preguntar *cual* se implementa, es el mismo ¿no? Si cambias la firma de uno de los métodos debes implementar los dos métodos **run** (sobrecarga) pero así, siendo los dos iguales...

Saludos

**EDITADO**

En este escenario:

```
interface I1 {
    public abstract int hacer();
}

interface I2 {
    public abstract int hacer();
}

public class Herencia implements I1, I2 {

    @Override
    public int hacer() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

el método `hacer` es el mismo. Para el compilador es exactamente lo mismo porque los dos métodos son iguales y van a hacer lo mismo - devolver un entero. Cómo se implementa la lógica es cosa de la clase pero el método es el mismo así que no hay problema.

Si hacemos esto:

```
interface I1 {
    public abstract int hacer(boolean b);
}

interface I2 {
    public abstract int hacer();
}

public class Herencia implements I1, I2 {

    @Override
    public int hacer() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int hacer(boolean b) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

al tener los dos métodos diferentes firmas el compilador nos obliga a implementar los dos.

Quiero decir que en el primer caso el compilador no *sabe* cual de los métodos es el que se implementa porque para él (el compilador) es solo un método, no dos, son iguales.